# jquery - dynamically created input form is not affected by jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a problem with an input form that should grow dynamically.

Here is my html code:

```
            <div id="div_pos">
                <p>
                    <input type=text name="pos_count1" style="width:30px">
                    <input type=text name="pos_name1" style="width:250px">
                    <input type=text class="pos" id="pos1" name="pos_value1" style="width:50px">
                </p>
            </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var counter = 1;
      $('.pos').keypress(function(event){

      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if(keycode == '13'){

        counter++;

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('p'));

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text" name="pos_count' + counter + '" style="width:30px"> ' + 
        '<input type=text name="pos_name' + counter + '" style="width:250px"> ' + 
        '<input type=text class="pos" id="pos'+ counter + '" name="pos_value' + counter + '" style="width:50px">');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#div_pos");
      }
   event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

The problem is that the new paragraph is only attended if the "Enter-Key" is hit in the first Input (id:pos1) and not in the created input fields of the pos class.
I tried to solve the problem with :

```
 $('.pos').keypress(function(event){
```

instead of

```
 $('#pos1').keypress(function(event){
```

But this does not work. Any ideas how to solve the problem? :)
And sorry for the worse title... did not know how to describe the problem exactly.

Comment: My browser crashed while trying to find most suitable duplicate of this question: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need event delegation. Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future. Use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#div_pos').on('keypress','.pos',function() {

});
```

**NOTE:** You need to specify the element you're binding your handler to as close to the target elements as possible to improve performance. In your case it's `#div_pos`, not `body` or `document`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `input` elements have been added dynamically to the DOM, all the events will not be available to these elements, you need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#div_pos').on('keypress','.pos',function(event) {
     // Your code here
});
```

So basically, this technique will help you to attach any type of event (in your case `keypress`) to these newly generated elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
$('#div_pos').on('keypress', '.pos', function(event)...
```

instead of

```
$('.pos').keypress(function(event)...
```

Alternately, you can recall $('.pos').keypress() after appending the elements.  From the API: **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().**

https://api.jquery.com/on/